# Error setting values for one VC for another VC

Tags: swift

I am trying to set the values of UILabel's on another view controller.  However I keep getting a nil value when I am trying to set temp values for the other view controller's UILabels and such.  This is the function that executes the segue:

```
func swipe(Sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!) {
    print("swiped left")
    let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OnDeck") as! OnDeck
    vc.firstBase = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(178, 136, 10, 10))
    vc.firstBase.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    vc.firstBase.layer.cornerRadius = vc.firstBase.frame.size.width/2

    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I am getting the following error on the line `vc.firstBase.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()`

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

is there something I am missing when attempting to declare the temp values for the outlets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set those related UI elements, because the UI haven't loaded yet. Instead, pass a value and set it in `viewDidLoad` of destination controller

```
class OnDeck: UIViewController {

    var color = UIColor.white()
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        ...
        firstBase = color
    }

}
```

Then in your `swipe` method, pass the value only rather than modify the unloaded `UILabel` or `UIView`. Else, move the UI related code to the destination `viewDidLoad()` such as the cornerRadius, frame size, etc